# Getting error of fetched items after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch

I am fetching my data from external API as usual and this is the typical way I do it:

**Fetch API:**

```
 const [tshirts, setTshirts] = useState([]);

    const fetchData = () => {
        fetch('apiEndpoint')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setTshirts(data[0].clothes.regular.top); // path to my array
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };
    React.useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);
```

**Map through an array:**

```
const tshirtArray = tshirts.tShirt; // specifying the path
const listItems = tshirtArray.map((item) => <li>{item}</li>);

<ul>{listItems}</ul>
```

**Example of data structure:**

```
[
  {
  id: 1,
  clothes: {
     regular: {
      top: {
        sleeveless: [],
        tShirt: [
          "image-path-here"
          ],
.....
.....
.....
```

When I first time execute the code it works, but after some time or after refreshing the page I get an error of **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')**

Why is that undefined? The path is correct and fetching the array should be as well. Can not find the reason of it not working.

Comment: tshirts is array initially, so you cannot take `tshirts.tShirt`

Comment: @sojin but how else I can fetch items from an array

Comment: You removed the other question so I'm commenting here: you had `<Component />`, i.e. weren't passing any props at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have reputation to comment, so let me try to clarify it for you through an answer. As @sojin mentioned, you cannot use tshirts.Tshirt since your state is of array type and arrays can't be used like objects, meaning that if there was an object of lets say exampleObject = { type: "shirt", color: "white } you could call it with exampleObject.type. Since you have an array of objects in your state (top that you are saving to state is still object which contains tShirt array), you first have to use index (to tell which object you want to use from the state array) and then you can use it like you wanted. For example, in your example there are 1 objects in state array. Array indexes start at 0. So you could do tshirts[0].tShirt to get the tShirt array from that object.

However, I would edit your code a bit. Instead of using tshirtArray constant, just do listItems from your state:

const listItems = tshirts.map((item) =>

{item.tShirt[0]}

);

Note: I've just used index 0 here to demonstrate the finding of the first item in tShirt array. If you want to see all tShirt image paths, then you may need to do nested mapping or other similar solutions.